# How can I skip SSL verification using libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am new to libgit2sharp (and git in general). I am trying to write a small program that handles multiple repositories in an unified manner. However, I've hit a brick wall when trying to deactivate the SSL verification. The library doesn't seem to provide an easy way to do this. I've found a branch (which seems to deal with the problem) and copied some code from [there](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/ec8b9ec0010d4f32fad37d03e47cfeb1fa12e1ac/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/SmartSubtransportFixture.cs)

My current code looks like this (I've deleted personal stuff"):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
//Additional code
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = certificateValidationCallback;
           GlobalSettings.RegisterSmartSubtransport<MockSmartSubtransport>("https");
//Additional code end
          //  Repository rep = new Repository(@"workingdirpath");
            Repository.Clone("url.git", "workingdirpath", new CloneOptions
            {
                CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(getCredentials),
                Checkout = true,
            });
            //Remote remote = rep.Network.Remotes.Add("master", "url.git");
            //rep.Network.Pull(new Signature("me", "me@company.de", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))), new PullOptions
            //    {
            //        FetchOptions = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(getCredentials), TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.Auto },
            //    });


        }

        private static Credentials getCredentials(string url, string usernameFromUrl, SupportedCredentialTypes types)
        {
            return new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = "myaccount",
                Password = "mypass",
            };
        }
```

The "MockSmartSubtransport" class can be found in the linked branch.

My problem is that, the code seems to work(it seems to disable the SSL verification), but I still get a "{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}" exception from the server. Without the additional code I get: " {"user cancelled certificate check: "}" from the server.

After debugging the thing it seems to me like the delegate for my credentials never gets called (although it gets registered for callback, when trying with either of the operations). I've checked that the username/password are correct by logging in on the server via Chrome and by committing with TortoiseGit.

At the moment I'm not sure that the SSL is still the problem or something else altogether.

Any ideas? If I am not specific enough about the problem I will try to give more info (please ask).

Comment: You keep mentioning SSL as an issue, but then you say that your problem is that you can't authenticate to the server. As these are two completely different things, could you specify which one you're currently having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

> After debugging the thing it seems to me like the delegate for my credentials never gets called

No.  They don't, because you've gone and registered your own subtransport.  This is not something that should be done without knowing exactly what you're doing.  This is not for trivial little things like SSL certificates, this is for when you have your own complete, existing HTTP stack that you want to use and you *simply can't* use the one that's included in LibGit2Sharp.

If you're experimenting thinking that maybe using your own subtransport will solve a very simple problem then *it won't*.  And pulling a test out and trying to make it actually work is likely to fail.

If you need to turn off SSL verification then use the `http.sslVerify` configuration setting.