# How to skip SSL verification in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

I recently started to use LibGit2Sharp and was able to start using this successfully. However, I am hitting one issue which I am unable to resolve related to SSL verification very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232877/how-can-i-skip-ssl-verification-using-libgit2sharp). For one of my scenario, I need to skip SSL verification.

I get the following exception when I try this scenario.

> user cancelled certificate check:

I tried using the solution mentioned in the link above which is as follows.

```
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => { return true; };
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = certificateValidationCallback;
GlobalSettings.RegisterSmartSubtransport<MockSmartSubtransport>("https");
```

I placed the above mentioned code before performing the git operation.

I see that the custom certificateValidationCallback is getting called. However, after that the git command fails with the following exception, "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Skipping the TLS certificate check is not currently supported. libgit2 used to honour `http.sslverify` but that was replaced with a callback to give the caller knowledge about what they were connecting to. This callback allows the user to allow the connection to continue or to abort it. It is unfortunately not implemented at the moment in libgit2sharp.

And as Edward says, replacing the whole HTTP stack is not going to solve much, especially when it's a fake one named so.

Comment: Do you have a reference? Or anyone knows if theres any update?

Answer (score 1):

> For one of my scenario, I need to skip SSL verification.

Then use the `http.sslVerify` configuration setting.  If that doesn't work, file an issue in LibGit2Sharp.  But don't try to use your own subtransport.

This is not something that should be done without knowing exactly what you're doing.  This is not for trivial little things like SSL certificates, this is for when you have your own complete, existing HTTP stack that you want to use and you *simply can't* use the one that's included in LibGit2Sharp.

If you're experimenting thinking that maybe using your own subtransport will solve a very simple problem then *it won't*.  And pulling a test out and trying to make it actually work is likely to fail.  Now *you* are responsible for everything like authentication and SSL handling.

Instead, turn off SSL verification with the `http.sslVerify` configuration setting.

Comment: Thanks Edward for your response. I will try this option. What I noticed is that the Library allows one to set config after the repo is cloned once as follows. In my case, I need to disable ssl verification in order to clone to the repo to over this issue. The other option is to disable this globally. However, I did not see any library methods which allow this to be set globally. Please let me know if you are aware of any.

Comment: @SachinChandraMohan Don't thank me, I think I'm wrong and that libgit2sharp doesn't honor that configuration setting.  I'll investigate further.

Comment: Here is the code to add config setting to a repo which I missed adding in my earlier comments.

var localRepo = new Repository(clonedRepoPath))
localRepo.Config.Set("http.sslVerify", "false");